# I want to split the string and should get specific text using C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split the string and to get specific text("Kernal Ltd") using split functionality. This is my following string,

`Your Quote - 12345- Kernal Ltd`

Tried to split the string with empty string and tried to get the string by index

```
var companyName = this.renewalSummaryPage.QuoteNameField.GetText().Split(
            new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Assert.AreEqual(CommonMessages.CompanyName, companyName[5]+" "+ companyName[6]);
```

Expected to get string of :

`Kernal Ltd`

Actual:

> index outside the bounds of the array error

Comment: why no one offer you to use `RegEx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split by spaces, then you will get `"Kernal"` and `"Ltd"` as two distinct entries. Split by `'-'` and don't rely on a specific number of parts. Instead look for the length of the resulting array.

```
string[] parts = "Your Quote - 12345- Kernal Ltd".Split('-');
string name = parts[parts.Length - 1].Trim(); // ==> "Kernal Ltd"
```

Array indexes are zero-based and range from `0` to `Length - 1`.

Or with Linq

```
string[] parts = "Your Quote - 12345- Kernal Ltd".Split('-');
string name = parts.Last().Trim();
```

Note that `String.Split` returns always at least one item. If the input string does not contain the split character(s), the whole string is returned in an array of length 1.

Comment: Does not handle possible `'-'` characters in the company name. I added a neat way of doing it below.

Comment: @DavidBentley: The problem is that we do not have specification of the possible inputs. Maybe the hyphen is always surrounded by spaces. Then we could split at `" - "`. This would probably exclude the ones inside a name `"Quote - 1234 - Best-Company"`.

Comment: True. We would definitely need to have a more concrete spec for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your indices are off by one. You have 5 spaces in the string, so that will result in 6 strings after `Split(" ")`. So you have to access `companyName[4]` and `companyName[5]`.

A more elegant solution would be:

```
int last = companyName.Count;
string companyNameString = companyName[last - 1] + " " + companyName[last];
```

But the best solution, assuming the format is always the following:

> <string> - <number> - <company name>

is:

```
string companyName = this.renewalSummaryPage.QuoteNameField.GetText().Split("-").LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yeah I assumed this is always the format. If it is not (for example, the company can have a name with >1 words, this won't work either).

Comment: Added an improved solution which should cover his cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide more context. If this is something reusable and the format is always the same, you could split and trim based on the `'-'` character. This will work assuming you do not have `'-'` in your company names. Remember this will FAIL if the format is not the same for your input.

```
var companyName = this.renewalSummaryPage.QuoteNameField.GetText().Split('-').LastOrDefault().Trim();
```

Now, if you have `'-'` characters in the company name...you can do the following. This will rebuild the string with the company name if `'-'` characters exist.

```
string[] parts = text.Split('-');
if (parts.Length > 2)
{
    companyName = string.Join("-", parts.Skip(2)).Trim();
}
else
{
    companyName = parts.LastOrDefault().Trim();
}
```